# JSF: /WEB-INF/*/javax.faces.resource/theme.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource (Primeface's resource URI has asterisk sign)

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

Using JSF, Spring, Spring WebFlow, PrimeFaces.
I'm trying to open simple 'hello world' page. Page itself is opened, but it throws such exception that it is not able to include Primeface's theme:

```
11:03:41,049 DEBUG FlowHandlerMapping:108 - Mapping request with URI '/spring/hello' to flow with id 'hello'
11:03:41,050 DEBUG FlowExecutorImpl:161 - Resuming flow execution with key 'e1s1
11:03:41,050 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:75 - Locking conversation 1
11:03:41,050 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:106 - Getting flow execution with key 'e1s1'
11:03:41,050 DEBUG FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl:58 - Getting FlowDefinition with id 'hello'
11:03:41,052 DEBUG ConditionalFlowExecutionListenerLoader:85 - Loaded [1] of possible 1 listeners for this execution request for flow 'hello', the listeners to attach are list[org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener@4a00e737]
11:03:41,053 DEBUG FlowExecutionImpl:250 - Resuming in org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.MvcExternalContext@5c282a38
11:03:41,057 DEBUG ViewState:286 - Rendering + [JSFView = '/WEB-INF/flows/hello.xhtml']
11:03:41,057 DEBUG ViewState:287 -   Flash scope = map[[empty]]
11:03:41,058 DEBUG ViewState:288 -   Messages = [DefaultMessageContext@1d152003 sourceMessages = map[[null] -> list[[empty]]]]
11:03:41,065 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:121 - Putting flow execution '[FlowExecutionImpl@499bfb44 flow = 'hello', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@7d3adf4c flow = 'hello', state = 'displayHelloView', scope = map['viewScope' -> map[[empty]]]]]]' into repository
11:03:41,066 DEBUG DefaultFlowExecutionRepository:128 - Adding snapshot to group with id 1
11:03:41,066 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:86 - Putting conversation attribute 'scope' with value map['flashScope' -> map['messagesMemento' -> map[[empty]]]]
11:03:41,066 DEBUG SessionBindingConversationManager:107 - Unlocking conversation 1
11:03:41,084 DEBUG FlowHandlerMapping:114 - No flow mapping found for request with URI '/spring/*/javax.faces.resource/theme.css'
May 04, 2018 11:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springFlowApplication] in context with path [/spring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.faces.FacesException: /WEB-INF/*/javax.faces.resource/theme.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource] with root cause
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/*/javax.faces.resource/theme.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView.renderMergedOutputModel(JsfView.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Page is being generated with such CSS link which contains also asterisk sign in href:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/spring/*/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo">
```

CSS itself without asterisk can be opened correctly with following link:

```
.../spring/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo
```

My POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jcg.examples.springWebFlowExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringWebFlowExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>SpringWebFlowExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.9</jsf.version>
        <primefaces.version>6.0</primefaces.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>          
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>           
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>blitzer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
            <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>  
            <version>1.0.1</version>  
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringWebFlowExample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

WEB.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version="2.5" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Spring-Flow Web-Application Example</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springFlowApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springFlowApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

webflow config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd">

    <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />

    <flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
            <flow:flow-execution-listeners>
                <flow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
            </flow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </flow:flow-executor>   

    <flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices">
        <flow:flow-location id="hello" path="/WEB-INF/flows/hello-flow.xml" />
    </flow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
    <faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />

    <faces:resources/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue updating url-pattern to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springFlowApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It would be very good if somebody could explain why needed to add '/app', because now whole URL also contains '../app/..', which is not very nice looking ...